# Why mpiexec (MPICH2) launch very slow on windows server 2012 R2?

Tags: mpi, windows-server-2012-r2, mpich

Platform: Windows server 2012 R2 Datacenter
Version: mpich2-1.3
Problem: I have installed mpich2 on my windows server before and I could start mpiexec quickly. However, recently I added a domain for my windows server. After I shifted to my new domain and account, mpiexec seems to start too slow. I tried re-install MPICH2, but it still takes about 2 minutes to start the example cpi.exe. My intent is to use MPICH2 to run another program, which is much bigger than cpi.exe, and even if an hour passes, the calculation seems not start. I am quite confused. If you know any solution/guidance, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this question by migrating MPICH2 to MS-MPI. The codes are the same, but some configures of Visual Studio Project should be changed. A good article for how to compile MS-MPI program in Visual Studio: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/windowshpc/2015/02/02/how-to-compile-and-run-a-simple-ms-mpi-program/